# Is there any way to download csv file from "website button click" using R

Tags: r

**download.file(URL, destfile = "../data.csv", method="curl")** need exact url of csv but i need to download the CSV file from a website having "*Download Click*" option.
"http://apps.who.int/gho/data/view.main.MHSUICIDEASDRREGv?lang=en" --> Link

Comment: try copying the url of download button and putting it in path

Comment: The download button necessarily point to the url of the file.

Comment: http://apps.who.int/gho/data/view.main.MHSUICIDEASDRREGv?lang=en --> this is the link, I need to download csv mentioned here  :Download complete data set as: CSV table  @AyushNigam

Comment: http://apps.who.int/gho/data/view.main.MHSUICIDEASDRREGv?lang=en --> this is the link, I need to download csv mentioned here  :Download complete data set as: CSV table @JRR

Comment: Right click button (or hyperlink), click "copy link", paste into R.

Comment: Thanks @AkselA able to copylink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hit F12 and see the code behind that page, and pretty much any page, except maybe flash elements.  Then, do something like this.

```
getit <- read.csv("http://apps.who.int/gho/athena/data/GHO/MH_12?filter=COUNTRY:-;REGION:*&x-sideaxis=REGION;SEX&x-topaxis=GHO;YEAR&profile=crosstable&format=csv")
head(getit)

getit <- fread("http://apps.who.int/gho/athena/data/GHO/MH_12?filter=COUNTRY:-;REGION:*&x-sideaxis=REGION;SEX&x-topaxis=GHO;YEAR&profile=crosstable&format=csv")

getit <- read_csv("http://apps.who.int/gho/athena/data/GHO/MH_12?filter=COUNTRY:-;REGION:*&x-sideaxis=REGION;SEX&x-topaxis=GHO;YEAR&profile=crosstable&format=csv")
```

You can find lots and lots of other ideas from the link below.

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-data-import-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

copy paste this :

```
download.file(url = "http://apps.who.int/gho/athena/data/GHO/MH_12?filter=COUNTRY:-;REGION:*&x-sideaxis=REGION;SEX&x-topaxis=GHO;YEAR&profile=crosstable&format=csv", destfile = "H:/test.csv")
```

i have used destination file path as "H:/test.csv" you can wherever u want to save the file